# How do I specify a minimum perl version for my distribution in Dist::Zilla dist.ini?

Tags: perl, version, dist-zilla

I'm working on my [Net::Prober](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::Prober) distribution, using [dzil](https://metacpan.org/module/Dist::Zilla). From the next version I'd like to enforce a **minimum requirement of perl 5.10+** (was 5.006), because I'm using named captures :-)

Now I have put `use 5.010;` at the top of my main module, and that's fine, but I was wondering: **is there a way to specify a minimum perl interpreter version in the `dist.ini` file**?

My current `dist.ini` is:

```
name    = Net-Prober
version = 0.07
...

[Prereqs]
Carp = 0
Data::Dumper = 0
Digest::MD5 = 0
IO::Socket::INET = 0
IO::Socket::SSL = 0
IO::Socket::UNIX = 0
LWPx::ParanoidAgent = 0
Net::Ping = 2.34
Sys::Syslog = 0

[Prereqs / TestRequires]
Test::More = 0
LWP::Online = 0

...
```

Can I just add `perl = 5.010` to the `[Prereq]` block?

Comment: Dist::Zilla seems to accept `perl = 5.010` in the `[Prereq]` block AFAICS :)

Comment: You could use the `distmeta` function to add a `MIN_PERL_VERSION => '5.010'` directive to your module's metadata.  The CPAN installers (any fairly recent version) will respect it.

Comment: \[AutoPrereqs\] will also detect `use 5.010;` in any module.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can I just add perl = 5.010 to the [Prereq] block?

Yes, you can. Alternatively, there's the [MinimumPerl](https://metacpan.org/module/Dist::Zilla::Plugin::MinimumPerl) plugin that autodetects the minimal version of perl that's required.

Comment: The MinimumPerl plugin (via [Perl::MinimumVersion](http://metacpan.org/module/Perl::MinimumVersion)) is a bit out of date though.. for example it doesn't detect any features introduced in 5.14 (and possibly 5.12) or later.

Comment: @Ether: It does detect features from 5.12 (including the ... operator), but you're right it hasn't been updated for 5.14 or higher. I'm sure Adam accepts patches ;-)

Comment: Looks like NEILB adopted this module in the meantime, so it has had some updates.